# Macbook M1 - Postgres Installation - "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" - Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew

I just got a new Macbook Pro M1 and have been trying to install Postgres with homebrew. After trying a bunch of different approaches from installing different versions of Postgres to trying `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` I've had no luck. I am at the point now where I can't even successfully install Postgres without an error message. When I uninstall and then reinstall use `brew install postgres` I get:

```
➜  ~ brew install postgres
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/postgresql/manifests/14.1_1
Already downloaded: /Users/landonlapensee/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/34e850b9c47867f84334b48fe844f7a171369d777b5c118a4119297f7c215147--postgresql-14.1_1.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/postgresql/blobs/sha256:027c8b48406c3d732241426e0f5d2caf9f48cb4d2d38610b8f5d46f0adf7a89f
Already downloaded: /Users/landonlapensee/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/b74d7a88df70e29d3cd5714896c2dd5b16a1e8c01188164026a4b5762f18234b--postgresql--14.1_1.monterey.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring postgresql--14.1_1.monterey.bottle.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.1_1/bin/initdb --locale=C -E UTF-8 /usr/local/var/postgres
Last 15 lines from /Users/landonlapensee/Library/Logs/Homebrew/postgresql/post_install.01.initdb:
Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /usr/local/var/postgres ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 20
selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
selecting default time zone ... America/Vancouver
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... 2021-12-07 10:07:39.032 PST [52558] FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Cannot allocate memory
2021-12-07 10:07:39.032 PST [52558] DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=1895806, size=56, 03600).
2021-12-07 10:07:39.032 PST [52558] HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded your kernel's SHMALL parameter.  You might need to reconfigure the kernel with larger SHMALL.
    The PostgreSQL documentation contains more information about shared memory configuration.
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using:
  brew postinstall postgresql
==> Caveats
To migrate existing data from a previous major version of PostgreSQL run:
  brew postgresql-upgrade-database

This formula has created a default database cluster with:
  initdb --locale=C -E UTF-8 /usr/local/var/postgres
For more details, read:
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-initdb.html

To restart postgresql after an upgrade:
  brew services restart postgresql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.1_1: 3,304 files, 43.9MB
==> Running `brew cleanup postgresql`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
```

Then if I run `brew services start postgres` I get:

```
➜  ~ brew services start postgres
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/landonlapensee/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist` exited with 5
```

If I run `psql` I get:

```
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/landonlapensee/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist` exited with 5.
➜  ~ psql
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

And if I run ➜  `~ rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` I get:

```
rm: /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid: No such file or directory
```

I am so lost on this issue. I am trying to set this up to use for a ruby on rails environment. Does anybody know what could be causing this issue? (I tried so many different threads/commands that I think I have created root files that are causing conflicts)

Or does anybody of any suggestions of any paid services that could walk me through fixing this?

BIG THANKS!

Comment: Did `brew postinstall postgresql` work?

Comment: No it didn't. I reinstalled with the postgres.app and it is working now.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Apparently it did not start the server after reinstalling because there was another server, postgresql@13 (the previous version before updating) still running. I killed the process and then it started the updated server.

Comment: How did you discover this? What commands did you run? Why did you have 2 versions? Please add more detail please.